# avconv video from single jpg and ogg

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04

I have a long ogg sounds file that I want to put on youtube, I don't have a video so want to display a single jpg for the duration for the ogg.  I've seen:

```
 avconv -i "sound file.ogg" -i cog.jpg out.avi
```

I have adjusted the jpg to be 640 x 480 but I get the following warnings:

```
 Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj420p' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'

 Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'ac3', auto-selecting format 'flt'
 [ac3 @ 0x18ae340] invalid bit rate
```

And it bombs out on:

```
 Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Any ideas on what parameters I could use to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing the full command line output this boils down to guessing, but it seems `avconv` selects the AC3 encoder for audio here, which isn't a useful default.

Try specifying the encoders you want to use. For YouTube, H.264 and AAC is recommended instead of MPEG-4 Part 2 video and AC3 audio.

```
avconv -loop 1 -i cog.jpg -i "sound file.ogg" \
-c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a libfaac -q:a 100 \
-shortest \
out.mp4
```

You should add the `-loop 1` option to force looping the image, and the `-shortest` option to stop encoding after there's no more audio. Instead of `-shortest` you can also specify `-t 00:02:30` to stop after 2:30 minutes, which would be more accurate than `-shortest`.

The above should work with any recent versions. Please note that `avconv` is not from FFmpeg, but [the Libav fork](http://libav.org/) and thus entirely unrelated to the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: It bombs out on: Unknown encoder 'libfaac' replacing it with: libvo_aacenc seems to do the trick

Comment: This one offers quite mediocre quality. Use `-c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k` for the native Libav one which is a little bit better, or install FAAC before installing Libav—it should then link against FAAC properly.